# PHP merging arrays by multiple factors

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of arrays like so:

```
[
    [
        "reference" => "CUSTOMER-LONDON",
        "Type" => "Clothing",
        "Currency" => "GBP",
        "shoppingBreakdownType" => "Mens",
        "shoppingBreakdown" => "socks",
        "shoppingBreakdownPrice" => 3.99,
        "color" => "red",
        "size" => "large",
        "refundAllowed" => true,
        "method" => "deniero"
    ],
    [
        "reference" => "CUSTOMER-LONDON",
        "Type" => "Clothing",
        "Currency" => "GBP",
        "shoppingBreakdownType" => "Mens",
        "shoppingBreakdown" => "Trousers",
        "shoppingBreakdownPrice" => 9.99,
        "color" => "blue",
        "size" => "small",
        "refundAllowed" => true,
        "method" => "BTC"

    ],
    [
        "reference" => "CUSTOMER-LONDON",
        "Type" => "HomeWare",
        "Currency" => "GBP",
        "shoppingBreakdownType" => "Mens",
        "shoppingBreakdown" => "towel",
        "shoppingBreakdownPrice" => 1.99,
        "color" => "yellow",
        "size" => "small",
        "refundAllowed" => true,
        "method" => "deniero"
    ],
    [
        "reference" => "CUSTOMER-LONDON",
        "Type" => "Clothing",
        "Currency" => "USD",
        "shoppingBreakdownType" => "Mens",
        "shoppingBreakdown" => "socks",
        "shoppingBreakdownPrice" => 3.99,
        "color" => "green",
        "size" => "medium",
        "refundAllowed" => true,
        "method" => "cash"
    ],
    [
        "reference" => "CUSTOMER-LONDON",
        "Type" => "Clothing",
        "Currency" => "USD",
        "shoppingBreakdownType" => "Mens",
        "shoppingBreakdown" => "Trousers",
        "shoppingBreakdownPrice" => 9.99,
        "color" => "pink",
        "size" => "medium",
        "refundAllowed" => true,
        "method" => "cash"
    ],
    [
        "reference" => "CUSTOMER-LONDON",
        "Type" => "HomeWare",
        "Currency" => "USD",
        "shoppingBreakdownType" => "Mens",
        "shoppingBreakdown" => "towel",
        "shoppingBreakdownPrice" => 1.99,
        "color" => "blue",
        "size" => "medium",
        "refundAllowed" => true,
        "method" => "card"
    ],
    [
        "reference" => "CUSTOMER-USA",
        "Type" => "Clothing",
        "Currency" => "USD",
        "shoppingBreakdownType" => "Mens",
        "shoppingBreakdown" => "socks",
        "shoppingBreakdownPrice" => 3.99,
        "color" => "yellow",
        "size" => "small",
        "refundAllowed" => true,
        "method" => "card",
    ],
    [
        "reference" => "CUSTOMER-USA",
        "Type" => "Clothing",
        "Currency" => "USD",
        "shoppingBreakdownType" => "Mens",
        "shoppingBreakdown" => "Trousers",
        "shoppingBreakdownPrice" => 9.99,
        "color" => "blue",
        "size" => "XXL",
        "refundAllowed" => true,
        "method" => "cash"
    ],
    [
        "reference" => "CUSTOMER-USA",
        "Type" => "HomeWare",
        "Currency" => "USD",
        "shoppingBreakdownType" => "Mens",
        "shoppingBreakdown" => "towel",
        "shoppingBreakdownPrice" => 1.99, ,
        "color" => "blue",
        "size" => "small",
        "refundAllowed" => true,
        "method" => "cash"
    ]
]
```

I am trying to loop through this array and merge them based on these rules:

If the `reference`, `type`, `currency`, `shoppingBreakdownType`, `method` are an exact match, then they should be merged into a single array with the difference in breakdowns added as new sub arrays like so:

```
[
    "reference" => "CUSTOMER-LONDON",
    "Type" => "Clothing",
    "Currency" => "GBP",
    "color" => "red",
    "size" => "large",
    "refundAllowed" => true,
    "method" => "deniero",
    "breakdownTypes": [
        {
            "shoppingBreakdownType" => "Mens",
            "breakdowns": [
                {
                    "shoppingBreakdown" => "socks",
                    "shoppingBreakdownPrice" => 3.99,
                },
                {
                    "shoppingBreakdown" => "towel",
                    "shoppingBreakdownPrice" => 1.99
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
],
[
    "reference" => "CUSTOMER-LONDON",
    "Type" => "Clothing",
    "Currency" => "GBP",
    "shoppingBreakdownType" => "Mens",
    "shoppingBreakdown" => "Trousers",
    "shoppingBreakdownPrice" => 9.99,
    "color" => "blue",
    "size" => "small",
    "refundAllowed" => true,
    "method" => "BTC"

],
[
    "reference" => "CUSTOMER-LONDON",
    "Type" => "Clothing",
    "Currency" => "USD",
    "shoppingBreakdownType" => "Mens",
    "shoppingBreakdown" => "socks",
    "shoppingBreakdownPrice" => 3.99,
    "color" => "green",
    "size" => "medium",
    "refundAllowed" => true,
    "method" => "cash",
    "breakdownTypes": [
        {
            "shoppingBreakdownType" => "Mens",
            "breakdowns": [
                {
                    "shoppingBreakdown" => "socks",
                    "shoppingBreakdownPrice" => 3.99,
                },
                {
                    "shoppingBreakdown" => "Trousers",
                    "shoppingBreakdownPrice" => 1.99
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
],

[
    "reference" => "CUSTOMER-USA",
    "Type" => "Clothing",
    "Currency" => "USD",
    "shoppingBreakdownType" => "Mens",
    "shoppingBreakdown" => "socks",
    "shoppingBreakdownPrice" => 3.99,
    "color" => "yellow",
    "size" => "small",
    "refundAllowed" => true,
    "method" => "card",
    "breakdownTypes": [
        {
            "shoppingBreakdownType" => "Mens",
            "breakdowns": [
                {
                    "shoppingBreakdown" => "socks",
                    "shoppingBreakdownPrice" => 3.99,
                },
                {
                    "shoppingBreakdown" => "Trousers",
                    "shoppingBreakdownPrice" => 9.99,
                },
                {
                    "shoppingBreakdown" => "towel",
                    "shoppingBreakdownPrice" => 1.99,
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
],

[
    "reference" => "CUSTOMER-LONDON",
    "Type" => "HomeWare",
    "Currency" => "USD",
    "shoppingBreakdownType" => "Mens",
    "shoppingBreakdown" => "towel",
    "shoppingBreakdownPrice" => 1.99,
    "color" => "blue",
    "size" => "medium",
    "refundAllowed" => true,
    "method" => "card"
]
```

as you can see, where those 5 values match. Then then a new child array is created called `breakdownTypes`, which has arrays grouped by `shoppingBreakdownType` with multiple items stored as arrays in `breakdowns`

I have spent nearly two days trying foreach loops and filters but I seem to get stuck in the loops and am unable to to get previous iteration data etc..

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: No, there isn't a simple way, you need to devise your own algorithm. Can you please share your best attempt and explain where and how it goes wrong?

Comment: The expected output you have shown, does not match your input data. Your first entry in there includes `"shoppingBreakdown" => "towel"`, but that is nowhere to be found in your input data in one of the elements with `"reference" => "CUSTOMER-LONDON", "Type" => "Clothing"`. _All_ your towel breakdowns in your input data are in `"Type" => "HomeWare"` elements.

Comment: (I don’t exactly see the point of having `breakdownTypes` be an array in your result structure. `shoppingBreakdownType` is one of the criteria you said you want to match, so there will only ever be _one_ entry in that array to begin with.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

You compared some of the subarrays keys to make the merge, but other keys like color are not considered and they could have different values, in this situation I preserve the first subarray value.

I don't unset subarrays values (shoppingBreakdown, shoppingBreakdownPrice, etc) because in your example in one case you unset them and in other case you don't. Unset lines are commented. You can't unset shoppingBreakdownType there because you need it to compare.

I don't compare shoppingBreakdown and shoppingBreakdownPrice to check if they are equal or not when two subarrays match, I put both of them into breakdownTypes.

```
<?php 

$res = array();

$keysToCompare = array("reference", "Type", "Currency", "shoppingBreakdownType", "method");

foreach($data as $dataSubArray) {
    $find = false;
    
    foreach($res as $resKey => $resSubArray) {
        $same = true;
        
        foreach($keysToCompare as $key) {
            if($dataSubArray[$key] != $resSubArray[$key]) {
                $same = false;
            }
        }
        
        if($same) {
            $find = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    if($find) {
        if(array_key_exists("breakdownTypes", $res[$resKey])) {
            $res[$resKey]["breakdownTypes"]["breakdowns"][] = array("shoppingBreakdown" => $dataSubArray["shoppingBreakdown"], "shoppingBreakdownPrice" => $dataSubArray["shoppingBreakdownPrice"]);
        } else {
            $res[$resKey]["breakdownTypes"] = array("shoppingBreakdownType" => $res[$resKey]["shoppingBreakdownType"],
                                                "breakdowns" => array (array("shoppingBreakdown" => $res[$resKey]["shoppingBreakdown"], "shoppingBreakdownPrice" => $res[$resKey]["shoppingBreakdownPrice"]),
                                                                        array("shoppingBreakdown" => $dataSubArray["shoppingBreakdown"], "shoppingBreakdownPrice" => $dataSubArray["shoppingBreakdownPrice"]))
            );
            
            /*
             unset($res[$resKey]["shoppingBreakdown"]);
             unset($res[$resKey]["shoppingBreakdownPrice"]);
             */
        }
        
        $find = false;
    } else {
        $res[] = $dataSubArray;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try later. I need a break from this task as it hurt my brain so much.

Comment: Sorry, I still need to test this. Apologies for late response.

Comment: No problem @JamesG!